# Is there serious reason why big company like Facebook or Google don't use front-end libraries such as jQuery?

Tags: google, javascript, facebook

I saw that Facebook like open-source software a lot. Is there some webmaster-specific reason why don't they use jQuery or another javascript library? 
Is that because jQuery/another js library has a "lot"<sup>[1]</sup> of kilobytes? Or another reason?

<sup>[1]</sup> I know it's only about 50kb, but you have to consider that's Facebook, a lot of traffic

Comment: The same question was closed at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445232/why-doesnt-facebook-use-jquery-or-similar) as not constructive.

Comment: Okay sorry. I didn't search on SO as I think it belongs here

Comment: I don't have "the" answer, though it would look weird (at best) if google guys would use jQuery instead of their own gwt, for example.

Comment: why weird? Even twitter use jQuery

Comment: @genesis Don't you think it would sound weird, if **GOOGLE** wouldn't use [**GOOGLE** Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/intl/it/webtoolkit/) in favour of someone else product like, to cite one, jQuery?

Comment: sorry, I thought that "gwt" is another shortcut